# Iterating over GTFS-RT protobuf message in python and editing it

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, gtfs

I need to read a *.pb file. I came accross this python library https://github.com/google/gtfs-realtime-bindings which appears to be able to parse the .pb file into a human readable format. It can also serialize the object back into a binary .pb

My problem is that I am finding it difficult to navigate the message.

I load it as such:

```
feed = gtfs_realtime_pb2.FeedMessage()
response = requests.get(url)
feed.ParseFromString(response.content)
message=feed.entity

for item in message:        
        if item.id==trip_id:
            if item.HasField('trip_update'):
                #do something with the item's fields
```

I have two problems:
I want to iterate over the subfields contained in "trip_update" and also change the values.Specifically,there is a number of stop_time_updates inside that I want to change.

Like so

```
id: "61443658"
trip_update {
  trip {
    trip_id: "61443658"
    start_time: "16:19:00"
    start_date: "20171027"
    schedule_relationship: SCHEDULED
    route_id: "17529"
    direction_id: 0
  }
  stop_time_update {
    departure {
      delay: 0
      time: 1509113940
    }
    stop_id: "54376"
    schedule_relationship: SCHEDULED
  }
  stop_time_update {
    arrival {
      delay: 0
      time: 1509114240
    }
    departure {
      delay: 0
      time: 1509114240
    }
    stop_id: "54633"
    schedule_relationship: SCHEDULED
```

Afterwards, I simply serialize the file.
There doesn't seem to be any available methods for navigating this feed entity object. If there is some way to do the above and I have missed it let me know, otherwise if you could point me into the right direction for the proper tool for what I want to do I'd be grateful.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified exactly what change you want to make, so the code sample below assumes you want to change the `delay` field for each of the StopTimeEvents (arrivals and departures) to 30 seconds. Note: I haven't actually tested this code.

```
feed = gtfs_realtime_pb2.FeedMessage()
response = requests.get(url)
feed.ParseFromString(response.content)
message = feed.entity

for item in message:        
    if not item.HasField('trip_update'):
        continue
    tu = item.trip_update
    for stu in tu.stop_time_update:  ## Loop over the stop_time_update repeated element
        if stu.HasField('arrival'):
            stu.arrival.delay = 30
        if stu.HasField('departure'):
            stu.departure.delay = 30
```

By the way, it looks like you are just consuming the API of some external feed generator, so it's not clear to me why you'd want to change the values rather than just read them.

Comment: If it is of any use can probably provide you with a java example for iterating through StopTimeUpdates and find a link to the gtfs realtime jar used